# Python: Randomly choose a spot on a tic-tac-toe board

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am writing a program that will essentially be a tic-tac-toe game. It uses a simple text based drawing of the board game using - lines and + pluses.
In the beginning of the program, I have the 9 spaces in the tic-tac-toe board defined as the following:

```
valuea1 = " "
valuea2 = " "
valuea3 = " "
valueb1 = " "
```

And so on through `valuec3`...
The blank spaces are set up to allow substitution of an X or an O.
My board function looks like this:

```
def board():
    """ prints the tic-tac-toe board"""
    print(" +---A------B------C--+")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("1|  " + valuea1 +"   |  " + valueb1 +"   |  " + valuec1 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" ----------------------")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("2|  " + valuea2 +"   |  " + valueb2 +"   |  " + valuec2 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" ----------------------")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("3|  " + valuea3 +"   |  " + valueb3 +"   |  " + valuec3 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" +--------------------+")
    return
```

Later on in the program, based on an if statement, the symbol the "computer player" will be using (either X or O) is stored in the variable:

```
computer_mark ## is either "X" or "O" based on player choice
```

**Now here is my main concern and question**

```
randomlist = ("valuea1", "valuec1", "valuea3", "valuec3")
random_result = random.choice(randomlist)
## (REPLACE WITH CODE)
## takes the value stored in random_result, somehow treats the value as a variable,
## assigns that given variable the string value that is stored in computer_mark
```

I try to randomly choose 1 of 4 spots on the board, and change that spot from a `" "` string value to the string value stored in computer_mark.

Is there a way to code Python into choosing a random variable, and assigning it a value that is stored in a different variable?

**EDIT**
I am a python and general programming noob. I've only been coding for two weeks, therefore, I apologize if my coding techniques are, somewhat, unintelligent.

Comment: I would suggest looking into using [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html), instead of having a variable for each option and randomly assigning to one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **very bad idea** to  try and modify these variables by name (if you really want to do this see below for an older answer). This is how you could improve your code by using a list instead of a bunch of variables:

```
import random

board = [' '] * 9

def set_random(board,computer_mark):
    board[random.randint(0, 8)] = computer_mark

def print_board(board):
    lines = [' +--%s--+' % ('-'*5).join(['A','B','C'])]
    for i in range(3):
        lines.append('%d|  %s  |' % (i,'  |  '.join(board[3*i:(3*i+3)])))
        if i < 2:
            lines.append(' ' + '-'*19)
    lines.append(' +%s+' % ('-'*17))
    print('\n |     |     |     |\n'.join(lines))

print_board(board)

random.seed(0)
set_random(board,'X')

print_board(board)
```

Output:

```
 +--A-----B-----C--+
 |     |     |     |
0|     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
1|     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
2|     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 +-----------------+
 +--A-----B-----C--+
 |     |     |     |
0|     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
1|     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
2|  X  |     |     |
 |     |     |     |
 +-----------------+
```

To better understand which list index goes into which field it is useful to visualize the indexes on the board:

```
>>> print_board(list(map(str,range(9))))
 +--A-----B-----C--+
 |     |     |     |
0|  0  |  1  |  2  |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
1|  3  |  4  |  5  |
 |     |     |     |
 -------------------
 |     |     |     |
2|  6  |  7  |  8  |
 |     |     |     |
 +-----------------+
```

---

You can access the current namespace (as a dict) using the `locals()` function. Thus you could to do the following: - This is however a **very bad idea**. See **above** for a **much** better way to tackle the general problem of representing and manipulating the board.

```
locals()[random_result] = computer_mark
```

**Edit** Based on the updated question a full example:

```
import random

valuea1 = valuea2 = valuea3 = valueb1 = valueb2 = valueb3 = valuec1 = valuec2 = valuec3 = " "

def board():
    """ prints the tic-tac-toe board"""
    print(" +---A------B------C--+")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("1|  " + valuea1 +"   |  " + valueb1 +"   |  " + valuec1 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" ----------------------")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("2|  " + valuea2 +"   |  " + valueb2 +"   |  " + valuec2 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" ----------------------")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print("3|  " + valuea3 +"   |  " + valueb3 +"   |  " + valuec3 + "   |")
    print(" |      |      |      |")
    print(" +--------------------+")
    return

random.seed(0) #to make this example reproducible
computer_mark = "X"

randomlist = ("valuea1", "valuec1", "valuea3", "valuec3")
random_result = random.choice(randomlist)
locals()[random_result] = computer_mark

board()
```

If I execute the above code I get the following result:

```
 +---A------B------C--+
 |      |      |      |
1|      |      |      |
 |      |      |      |
 ----------------------
 |      |      |      |
2|      |      |      |
 |      |      |      |
 ----------------------
 |      |      |      |
3|      |      |  X   |
 |      |      |      |
 +--------------------+
```

Comment: I will try to look into lists most definitely. Problem is that I tried the locals() way, and I still get the same result. My board remains, specifically, my board values remain empty.

Comment: What do you mean by ' same result'?

Comment: I updated my OP to show how my "board" looks like. Sorry if i make things confusing. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should of ran your code on a separate file. Apparently something within my full program is causing an issue. Your method works perfectly, however. Thank-you.

Comment: my board() function, as well as the rest of my code, was nestled in a bigger function. I guess I just don't know how functions work yet I guess. So I removed that and replaced it with a while True statement. I wanted to make the game re-playable but apparently nestling all my code within a function that I could call again was a bad idea.

Comment: Depends. If it was calling itself then you'll hit the maximum recursion limit very fast ... If you have a question about that in general just add your code to a new question and you'll surely get some help

Comment: As you now know [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907687/function-within-a-function-issue#comment70997513_41907786), advising to update the dictionary returned by `locals()` is very bad advice. Can you remove that advice from this answer to avoid confusing others who may come across it?

Comment: It is the  only way to do what the OP wanted (apart from using eval / exec which is probably only slightly better) ... That that is not a good idea is totally unrelated. You are however right that I should make it much more clear that it is a very bad idea to change locals() and expect consistent behaviour.

Comment: I have now switched the order of the solutions and hopefully made it very clear that trying to modify the variables is not the best approach

Comment: For reference: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Thanks again for responsibly fixing this answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the issue. My wall of text made me kind of blind to it ...

Answer (score 2):

You should definetly consider using a `list` or a nested list for this:

```
import random

board = [[' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Then you can access a random field (the main list contains 3 lists each containing 3 items:

```
random_field = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
board[random_field[0]][random_field[1]] = 'x'
print(board)
# [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', 'x'], [' ', ' ', ' ']]  # just one example
```

Or if you want a random choice out of several possibilities:

```
random_field = random.choice([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
board[random_field[0]][random_field[1]] = 'x'
print(board)
# [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'x', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]  # sets only one of the diagonals
```

Comment: Indeed, although I'd consider using a single 9-element one-dimensional array, and only showing it as a grid when you go to display it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've only been coding for about 2 weeks and have not gotten to lists yet. But I might as well start researching it and trying out since i'm on the subject. I'll use ure example and the other replier's as samples to help me learn.

Comment: @IrvinLesh ok, in that case I shouldn't have used nested lists in the example, I assumed you knew about `lists` because you used a `tuple` in `("valuea1", "valuec1", "valuea3", "valuec3")` :)

Comment: @DavidZ You're definetly right. I chose the nested list mostly because it's visually (without display function) more intuitive than a not-nested list.

Comment: @MSeifert I learn as I go. When I'm coding something and I need to know how to do something I don't know yet, I just google it and learn the concept that way. Its been working out great. I'm also using some online books as references to try to push me in the right direction.

Comment: I have used your great suggestions to update my answer with an example of how the code could be changed to use a list instead of a bunch of variables.